Moderator Pro Tem Announcement
Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: Moderators Pro Tempore.
I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed.



We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.
Did I overlook anyone?
Almost certainly. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in no way a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why you'll have your elections once your site has graduated.
Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Let's also thank these other users, for having stepped up to moderate in the past:




Nice ! Congratulation to the new moderators ! :)

@CamilStaps I think you should make it an answer.

@Shog9: any ETA when the site graduates?

@Ange We are quite some time away from that. A few months at least.

@CamilStaps: it's fine, I think AshRj is a good choice, although I also wonder why Igor didn't make it. But then what do I know. Congratulations to the new moderators!

Welcome @Igor! You are in for an interesting and rewarding experience. Congratulations! And all the best!

I'd say we're certainly forgetting @Igor Skochinsky when looking at the Who should the moderators be? thread.
note: I failed to figure out how to properly link to an existing thread on the meta site. feel free to fix-edit

Yeah I'm a bit surprised by the fact he's not on here. I suppose this is just temporary so I'm pretty sure it will change once the elections are held. It possible that Igor declined the temporary moderator position.

Yes. I was expecting him here too.

same - I can only assume that he refused, that'd be the only valid reason to me.

Igor stated he would prefer to focus on answering questions at this time - since that's definitely not something we would want to discourage, I opted to go with other volunteers. He could always run in an election at some point (or be appointed, if the beta lasts long enough).

Shog9, thanks for the response. Makes complete sense.

Yep that's correct. Don't really have time for moderating right now, too.
